# IE9 submit button does not work

Tags: asp.net, authentication, submit, internet-explorer-9

I have a login page which works on firefox, chrome and ie7 but suddenly submit button has stopped working on ie9 and does not respond at all. I searched but could not find anything causing it. [My login page](http://www.bodto.com.tr/login.aspx)

Comment: validator.w3.org reports a few XHTML Strict validation errors for your login page.  Does it help if you fix those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two forms on this page, delete the form has a language dropdown and I suppose it will be just fine.

Comment: I have two forms on home page under http://bit.ly/q48UmE but it is displayed without empty line. One is between body tags, other is in languageselector div.

Comment: @user574712 Have you tried what i suggested on login page? on login page "Giriş yap" works cause it just posts the form. But on login page it does some validation and with multiple forms it simply is not working. Btw why are you using language selecter dropdown in a form? you can create and ascx and add it to your master page?

Comment: On IE 9, "Giriş Yap" does not work at all even though I commented out language selector. Language selector is already created as a usercontrol an it is attached on master page. I dont get why it works with IE7, Chrome and Firefox but not with IE9 and IE8